# Calling javascript Method from Code behind using ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am using Ajax Toolkit on my content page . I have an Javascript Code which i want to call from the code behind using `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript`.

The javaScript Code is :-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function disp_confirm() {
       var r = jConfirm("Your Shift End ! Do you still want to Continue ? ")
       if (r == true) {
           jAlert("You pressed OK!")
       }
       else {
           jAlert("You pressed Cancel!")
       }
```

How to call this `disp_confirm()`method of javascript from the code behind using C# .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page,GetType(),"disp_confirm","<script>disp_confirm()</script>",false)
```

Comment: how about this.....?    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N"), "ScriptFunName();", true);

Answer (score 5):

```
 System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, typeof(System.Web.UI.Page), "Script", "myFun();", true);
```

this worked for me

Answer (score 2):

If one use Asp.net UpdatePanel control from ajax toolkit then we need to use ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript

Code:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "Javascript", "javascript:disp_confirm(); ", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

In short, you cannot fire javascript from codebehind without first having to refresh the page to take into account the javascript code you inject.

Basically, with RegisterStartupScript, youre telling asp to inject some javascript on page load. but this wont help if you need to dynamically call a javascript function or variable.

What you can take away from my example: 
I have a div covering the ASP control that I want both javascript and codebehind to be ran from. The div's onClick method AND the calendar's OnSelectionChanged event both get fired this way.

In this example, i am using an ASP Calendar control, and im controlling it from both javascript and codebehind:

Front end code:

```
        <div onclick="showHideModal();">
            <asp:Calendar 
                OnSelectionChanged="DatepickerDateChange" ID="DatepickerCalendar" runat="server" 
                BorderWidth="1px" DayNameFormat="Shortest" Font-Names="Verdana" 
                Font-Size="8pt" ShowGridLines="true" BackColor="#B8C9E1" BorderColor="#003E51" Width="100%"> 
                <OtherMonthDayStyle ForeColor="#6C5D34"> </OtherMonthDayStyle> 
                <DayHeaderStyle  ForeColor="black" BackColor="#D19000"> </DayHeaderStyle>
                <TitleStyle BackColor="#B8C9E1" ForeColor="Black"> </TitleStyle> 
                <DayStyle BackColor="White"> </DayStyle> 
                <SelectedDayStyle BackColor="#003E51" Font-Bold="True"> </SelectedDayStyle> 
            </asp:Calendar>
        </div>
```

Codebehind:

```
        protected void DatepickerDateChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (toFromPicked.Value == "MainContent_fromDate")
            {
                fromDate.Text = DatepickerCalendar.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString();
            }
            else
            {
                toDate.Text = DatepickerCalendar.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString();
            }
        }
```